# Sybase SQL update with self-join

Tags: sql, sybase, self-join

What's the right syntax in Sybase SQL to do an update with a self join? E.g. assuming you have the below table (#tmptbl):

```
account | client  |amount | date
-------------------------------------
ACT1    | CLIENTA | 12    |2010-12-30
ACT2    | CLIENTB | 5     |2010-12-30
ACT1    | CLIENTA | 17    |2010-12-31
ACT2    | CLIENTB | 6     |2010-12-31
```

I want to overwrite the amounts on 2010-12-31 with the amount values from 2010-12-30.

I feel like writing something like this:

```
update old
set old.amount = new.amount
from #tmptbl old,  #tmptbl new
where 
/*filter old*/
old.account = 'ACT1' 
and old.date = '2010-12-30' 
and old.client = 'CLIENTA' 
/* self-join new and old*/
and old.account = new.account 
and old.client = new.client 
/* filter new */
and new.date = '2010-12-31'
```

But it doesn't look like Sybase accepts an alias in the 'update <>' clause. What's the proper way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
update #tmptbl
set old.amount = new.amount
from #tmptbl old,  #tmptbl new
where 
/*filter old*/
old.account = 'ACT1' 
and old.date = '2010-12-30' 
and old.client = 'CLIENTA' 
/* self-join new and old*/
and old.account = new.account 
and old.client = new.client 
/* filter new */
and new.date = '2010-12-31' 
go
```

If you leave out the alias of the table you are updating, i.e. `set amount = new.amount` then Sybase associates the table you are updating with the *first* matching table in the from clause, so in that case for your update to work you'd need the from to read `from  #tmptbl new, #tmptbl old`.

Output:

```
 account     client     amount     date             
 ----------  ---------  ---------  ---------------- 
 ACT1        CLIENTA    12         30/12/2010 00:00 
 ACT2        CLIENTB    5          30/12/2010 00:00 
 ACT2        CLIENTB    6          31/12/2010 00:00 
 ACT1        CLIENTA    12         31/12/2010 00:00
```

Comment: Is that why when I did "set new.amount = old.amount from #tmptbl old, #tmptbl new" I got "Warning : Ambiguous table to update; Using the table specified in the update clause."?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
update #tmptbl 
set amount = new.amount
from #tmptbl old,  #tmptbl new
where 
/*filter old*/
old.account = 'ACT1' 
and old.date = '2010-12-30' 
and old.client = 'CLIENTA' 
/* self-join new and old*/
and old.account = new.account 
and old.client = new.client 
/* filter new */
and new.date = '2010-12-31'
```

Comment: Yep - works, thanks. Had to accept  the other answer as it was a bit more detailed.

Comment: @user779 that's fine. I was guessing anyway since its been a good decade since I've had a Sybase DB to play with :)